# Does crashlytics log fatal errors?

Tags: crashlytics

I am wondering if Crashlytics logs fatal errors, and if so, when? At next app run? I am not sure what the flow is so I am just trying to make sure I understand when the Fatal error will actually make its way to their backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Yes, if an app experiences a fatal exception, we will capture and then resend it when the user relaunches the app with an active network connection.